# Excel Vba error in 'For" statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm taking a random sample of 3% of report hits per report per market..yeah, don't ask. Anyway - I have the code all set and done, I have markets and reports set up as an array

ex: market = Array("market1", "market2","market3"...)
report = Array("report1", "report2", "report3"...)

my problem is that when I run the code to get 3%, when there is no report hits for that market - I get a duplicate of the previous report.

the data looks like this:

market1 | report1 | #of hits

market1 | report2 | #of hits

Market1 | report3 | #of hits

**market2 | report1 |#of hits**

**market2 | report1 | #of hits**

market2 | report3 | #of hits

How do I eliminate the duplication of the previous data?

here is my code:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(market)
For z = 0 To UBound(report)

    
    reporthits = Application.CountIfs(ws2.Range("B:B"), market(i), ws2.Range("L:L"), report(z))
       
    If reporthits * 0.03 < 1 Then
    samplecount = 1
    Else
    samplecount = Round(reporthits * 0.03, 0)
    End If

    rownumber = ws2.Evaluate("IFERROR(Match(""" & market(i) & report(z) & """,B:B & L:L, 0),""Not Found"")")
        
    
    If IsNumeric(rownumber) Then

ws2.Range("$A" & rownumber & ":$L" & (rownumber + (samplecount - 1))).Copy
lrow3 = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws3.Range("A" & lrow3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Else: Resume Next
```

thanks!

Comment: That is because no match is being found and row number is `"Not Found"` which would throw an error, but your `on error resume next` forces it to the next line and it pastes the last cell that was copied.  You need to test whether rownumber is a number or a string.  Only do the copy and paste if rownumber is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
on error resume next
ws2.Range("$A" & rownumber & ":$L" & (rownumber + (samplecount - 1))).Copy

lrow3 = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws3.Range("A" & lrow3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

with

```
If Isnumeric(rownumber) Then
    ws2.Range("$A" & rownumber & ":$L" & (rownumber + (samplecount - 1))).Copy

    lrow3 = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws3.Range("A" & lrow3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End If
```